# How can I send feedback on a submitted assginment in java?

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm trying to send feedback on a submission in my java application.
In teams I would submit it in the feedback box here:

[image]

This is the request I'm sending with `GraphClient`:

```
_userClient.education()
  .classes(classId)
  .assignments(assignmentsId)
  .submissions(submissionID)
  .outcomes()
  .buildRequest()
  .post(outcome);
```

And this is how I get the outcome:

```
EducationItemBody body = new EducationItemBody();
body.content = message;
body.contentType = BodyType.TEXT;

EducationFeedback feedback = new EducationFeedback();
feedback.text = body;

EducationFeedbackOutcome outcome = new EducationFeedbackOutcome();
outcome.feedback = feedback;
outcome.publishedFeedback = feedback;
```

I know that there are different types of `EducationOutcomes` as described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/educationoutcome?view=graph-rest-1.0). I've based my Graph request on [the request for posting an education outcome with a file-based resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/educationfeedbackresourceoutcome-post-outcomes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), however I just want a text-based feedback, so I've used the `EducationFeedbackOutcome` model. I tried using the `EducationFeedbackResourceOutcome` model as described in the example, but it doesn't exist in the Graph SDK

Now when I send the request I get an error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "20243",
    "message": "Invalid request body. Resource cannot be null.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2023-04-14T13:24:55",
      "request-id": "6fdd2196-6d77-4414-93ae-b7d2ef92d14a",
      "client-request-id": "3cf86b17-59b9-4c9e-9687-49af6e25626d"
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that it expects a resource, but that is neither what I want, nor what I can give. I've filled out all the fields in the EducationOutcome. There is no "resource"  field.

How can I submit feedback to an assignment using java? Maybe I need to use a different edpoint?